# Bootstrap style not applying to dynamic checkbox

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, append

Sample[image]

the Primary Contact is a static element, when I generate another which is contact 2, the css changes for the checkbox.

this is the code I use to add another element

```
$(document.body).on('click', "#add-user", function (){  
        var counter = $('#counter-user').val();
        counter++;
        $('#user-new').append("<tr data-id='"+ counter +"'><td><div class='row' ><div class='form-group col-md-4 col-sm-12'><label class='control-label col-md-12' style='text-align:left;font-size:16px'><b>Contact "+ counter +"</b></label> </div></div><div class='row' ><div class='form-group col-md-4 col-sm-12'><label class='control-label col-md-4'>First <span class='required'> * </span> </label> <div class='col-md-8'><div class='input-icon right'><i class='fa'></i><input type='text' class='required caps trim form-control' name='efirst"+ counter +"'/> </div></div></div><div class='form-group col-md-4 col-sm-12'><label class='control-label col-md-4'>Last <span class='required'> * </span> </label><div class='col-md-8'><div class='input-icon right'> <i class='fa'></i><input type='text' class='required caps trim form-control' name='elast"+ counter +"'/> </div></div></div><div class='form-group col-md-4 col-sm-12'><label class='control-label col-md-4'>Title </label> <div class='col-md-8'><div class='input-icon right'><i class='fa'></i><input type='text' class='form-control caps trim ' name='etitle"+ counter +"'/> </div></div></div></div><div class='row' ><div class='form-group col-md-4 col-sm-12'><label class='control-label col-md-4'>Phone </label> <div class='col-md-8'><div class='input-icon right'><i class='fa'></i><input type='text' class='numbers validate-phone form-control trim user-phone mask-phone' name='ephone"+ counter +"'/> </div></div></div><div class='form-group col-md-4 col-sm-12'> <label class='control-label col-md-4'>Mobile </label><div class='col-md-8'><div class='input-icon right'><i class='fa'></i> <input type='text' class='numbers validate-phone form-control trim user-phone mask-phone' name='emobile"+ counter +"'/> </div> </div> </div> <div class='form-group col-md-4 col-sm-12'> <label class='control-label col-md-4'>Department </label> <div class='col-md-8'> <div class='input-icon right'> <i class='fa'></i> <input type='text' class='form-control caps trim ' name='edept"+ counter +"'/> </div> </div> </div></div> <div class='row' > <div class='form-group col-md-4 col-sm-12'> <label class='control-label col-md-4'>Email <span class='required'>*</span> </label> <div class='col-md-8'> <div class='input-icon right'> <i class='fa'></i> <input type='text' class='required validate-email form-control trim' name='eemail"+ counter +"'> </div> </div> </div><div class='form-group col-md-4 col-sm-12'> <label class='control-label col-md-4'>Fax </label> <div class='col-md-8'> <div class='input-icon right'> <i class='fa'></i> <input type='text' class='numbers validate-phone form-control trim user-phone mask-phone' name='efax"+ counter +"'/> </div> </div> </div> <div class='form-group col-md-4 col-sm-12'> <label class='control-label col-md-4'>Notification<span class='required'>*</span> </label> <div class='col-md-8'> <div class='form-group col-md-4 col-sm-12' style='margin-right:20px'> <label class='control-label' style='font-size:12px;'>Email </label> <input type='checkbox' class='form-control' name='not-email"+ counter +"' id='eemail' value='yes' data-user-count='"+ counter +"' checked /></div> <div class='form-group col-md-4 col-sm-12' style='margin-right:20px'> <label class='control-label' style='font-size:12px;'>Text </label> <input type='checkbox' class='form-control notif' name='not-text"+ counter +"' id='emobile' value='yes' data-user-count='"+ counter +"'/></div><div class='form-group col-md-4 col-sm-12'> <label class='control-label' style='font-size:12px;'>Fax </label><input type='checkbox' class='form-control notif' name='not-fax"+ counter +"' id='efax'  value='yes' data-user-count='"+ counter +"'/></div></div></div></div></td></tr>");
        $('#counter-user').val(counter);
        $(".user-phone").inputmask("(999) 999-9999");
        $('#remove-user').show();
    });
```

Comment: Dont add so much html like that. That is miserable code.

Comment: Use [jquery clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) ... please

Comment: @gerdi if I use clone how can I change the id of the cloned element ex: id="elem1" the cloned element should contain id="elem2"

Comment: `$('#user-new').clone().data("id",counter)` ... some combination of that... clone -> find new tr -> find data-id -> change value . From the code above you should $.each() on the elements you want to add the counter

Comment: @gerdi clone doesn't let me click the checkbox after cloning

Comment: @gerdi it doesn't let me click (check/uncheck) the checkbox after cloning

Comment: I think you seem to be mistaken. added elements , whether adding them in massive strings or through magic, need to be bound to the DOM with [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) . Try not to approach problems directed toward a framework. The only people that are allowed to do that are those that create frameworks ;) https://jsfiddle.net/cp9av4je/2/

Answer (score 1):

Your checkbox should not have the class 'form-control'.  If you remove it, it will look normal.

I'm not sure which styles you want, but by default bootstrap checkboxes don't look like the ones in the first section of your image.  They are grey and look like normal checkboxes:

[image: bootstrap checkboxes]

Perhaps you have your own styles you applied that you aren't applying to the new elements?

Comment: the checkbox just reverted to a regular checkbox, but the styles are still different

Comment: the primary contacts checkbox has that class so they should be identical when i append the similar checkbox